Unable to execute the correct video after filtering
I am implementing a video player application.
Here, I have this requirement that if I am clicking on any video name (li), it should get played.
This is working fine. But when I am filtering the videos by providing input and clicking on video name in the filtered set, it is displaying video 1 by default and giving me this error
script.js:59 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url')
at playvideo1 (script.js:59:50)
at HTMLLIElement.
In playVideo1, I am getting the correct playlist but curr is always 1.
html code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Music Player</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="videos.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="music-player">
        <div class="player-info">
            <h3 id="video-title"></h3>
            <p id="video-artist"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <button id="prev-button">Previous</button>
            <button id="play-button">Play</button>
            <button id="next-button">Next</button>
            <button id="shuffle-button">Click to Shuffle</button>
            <video id="video" controls preload="auto">
                <source id="video-src" type="video/mp4">
            </video>

        </div>
        <div class="video-list-box">
            <input type="text" id="search-input" placeholder="Search video">
            <div class="playlist">
                <ul id="video-list">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

JS Code
// Reference the <video> and the <source> elements
const video = document.getElementById('video');
const videoSource = document.getElementById('video-src')

// Reference other DOM elements
const videoList = document.getElementById("video-list");
const searchInput = document.getElementById('search-input');

// Create a copy of the original video playlist
const originalList = [...videos];

// Initialize variables to track the current video index and shuffle state
let currentvideoIndex = 0;
let isShuffle = false;

// Function to update the video playlist displayed in the UI
function updatePlayList(playlist) {
    videoList.innerHTML = '';
    console.log("***", playlist)
    for (i = 0; i < playlist.length; i++) {
        let liElement = document.createElement("li");
        // Display the video title in the playlist
        liElement.innerHTML = `${Object.values(playlist[i])[0]}`
        liElement.addEventListener('click', () => { playvideo1(playlist, i) })
        console.log(liElement.innerHTML, i)
        videoList.appendChild(liElement);
    }
    // playlist.forEach(video => {
    //     let liElement = document.createElement("li");
    //     // Display the video title in the playlist
    //     liElement.innerHTML = `${Object.values(video)[0]}`
    //     videoList.appendChild(liElement);
    // });    
}

// Function to update the UI with video information
function updateUI(currentvideoIndex, playlist) {
    document.getElementById('video-title').textContent = playlist[currentvideoIndex]["title"];
    document.getElementById('video-artist').textContent = playlist[currentvideoIndex]["artist-name"];
}

// Function to play the current video
function playvideo(playlist) {
    video.pause();
    // Set the video source
    videoSource.src = playlist[currentvideoIndex]["url"];
    // Load and play the video after setting the source
    video.load();
    video.play();
    // Update the UI with video information
    updateUI(currentvideoIndex, playlist);
}

function playvideo1(playlist, curr) {
    console.log("333333333", playlist, "(((((", curr)
    video.pause();
    // Set the video source
    currentvideoIndex = curr;
    videoSource.src = playlist[currentvideoIndex]["url"];
    // Load and play the video after setting the source
    video.load();
    video.play();
    // Update the UI with video information
    updateUI(currentvideoIndex, playlist);
}


// Event delegation for video selection in the playlist
videoList.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (e.target.tagName === 'LI') {
        currentvideoIndex = [...videoList.children].indexOf(e.target);
        // Play the selected video, considering the shuffle state
        playvideo(isShuffle ? videos : originalList);
    }
});

// Event listeners for play, next, and previous buttons
document.getElementById('play-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    playvideo(isShuffle ? videos : originalList);
});

document.getElementById('next-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Move to the next video and play it
    currentvideoIndex = (currentvideoIndex + 1) % videos.length;
    playvideo(isShuffle ? videos : originalList);
});

document.getElementById('prev-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Move to the previous video and play it
    currentvideoIndex = (currentvideoIndex - 1 + videos.length) % videos.length;
    playvideo(isShuffle ? videos : originalList);
});

// Function to shuffle the array in place
function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
    }
}

// Event listener for the Shuffle button
document.getElementById('shuffle-button').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    isShuffle = !isShuffle;

    if (isShuffle) {
        event.target.textContent = "Click to Unshuffle";
        // Shuffle the playlist, update it, and play the first video
        shuffleArray(videos);
        updatePlayList(videos);
        currentvideoIndex = 0;
        playvideo(videos);
    } else {
        event.target.textContent = "Click to Shuffle";
        // Restore the original playlist, update it, and play the first video
        updatePlayList(originalList);
        currentvideoIndex = 0;
        playvideo(originalList);
    }
});

// Event listener to filter the playlist based on search input
searchInput.addEventListener('input', () => {
    const searchTerm = searchInput.value.toLowerCase();
    const filteredvideos = originalList.filter((video) =>
        video.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
    );
    // Update the displayed playlist with the filtered videos
    updatePlayList(filteredvideos);
});

// Initialize the playlist and UI with the original list
updatePlayList(originalList);
updateUI(currentvideoIndex, originalList);


The error is telling you that playlist[currentvideoIndex] doesn't have the property "url", it's undefined. Besides the point, I'd personally find a different way of maintaining your current currentvideoIndex variable. You're combining using it in the global scope as well as establishing it as a function parameter, causing the code to be far less readable. Good luck!
